# How to create a step-down ac transformer without primary coil?

Tags: transformer, ac-dc

I am currently trying to build a coil gun for a school project in an engineering program and am facing certain resource constraints put on me by the professor.
I have looked at many different coil gun builds from other people but they tend to use super capacitors or 20 volt batteries among other things in order to achieve the current required to move the projectile. I am limited to a 5V battery, a list of components (diodes, 1000uF capacitors, MOSFETS...), and a $50 budget but at least half of that must go towards the coil itself.
I figure the battery will not be enough to create a large current that can accelerate the projectile to a reasonable speed (please correct me if I am wrong in this assumption and inform me of how I would be able to set this up).
I am currently thinking that maybe using the power outlet (I'm in Canada so 120VAC) could be an option but I can't buy a transformer with my budget.
Using the diodes to convert it to dc and then resistors to step down the voltage could I safely bring it down to 50V DC?
It seems like it is not feasible since I haven't seen any designs that do this but I am curious why this wouldn't work if it doesn't.

Comment: `could I safely bring it down to 50V DC?` .... you could bring the output down to 50 Vdc, but the circuit would not be safe to touch, since any part of the circuit would be at line voltage with respect to an earth grounded object ... the 50 V output would be steady state only if the output current did not change because the voltage drop across the resistors would vary with the current through the resistors

Comment: Would I also be able to use this setup to charge capacitors and then use those capacitors to create the high voltage in the coil? Or would it be to dangerous to touch these components due to the way I have set the circuit up?

Comment: You say you are limited to a list of components, but you are asking about things that are not on the list. It appears that you are bing pushed to store as much energy as possible in the capacitor and then use that in the most efficient way to accelerate the projectile. I don't think that you have sufficiently thought about the problem and attempted to solve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework problem with insufficient demonstration of effort to solve.

Comment: For the purpose of the coil gun circuit I have access to diodes, 1000uF capacitors, MOSFETS, resistors, and photocells(for sensing when the projectile passes through the coil to turn it off). My capacitors are rated for 40 volts. I would like to charge the capacitors to the full 40 yet I only have access to a 5 volt battery or 120v wall outlet. I have spoken to multiple professors about this problem and they were not able to answer my question due to the complexity(basically they understood the theory behind how it would work but not how to make it work).

Comment: Please let me know if there are better resources for me that would help me overcome these obstacles.

Comment: Photocells are typically far too slow for this application. You'd need photodiodes or phototransistors.

Comment: You need to build a step -up converter to raise your 5 V battery to 40 V. If you're not allowed inductors, then you could make a charge pump with your MOSFETs diodes and capacitors.